# Errno 13 Permission denied: '/storage/ emulated/0/Download/site.html'

Tags: android, kivy, android-permissions, kivymd, android-11

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp

from kivy.base import Builder

from kivymd.toast import toast

from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

import ssl

import requests

# Import necessary Android modules

from jnius import autoclass

from android import mActivity

# Request storage permission

request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])

# Get the storage path

context = mActivity.getApplicationContext()

storage_path = os.path.join(os.environ['EXTERNAL_STORAGE'], 'Download')

KV='''

#my design

'''

class MainApp(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

                

    def build(self):

        return Builder.load_string(KV)    

    def download_site(self):

        try:

            url = self.root.ids.site_link.text

            response = requests.get(url,verify=False)

            if response.status_code == 200:

                filename = os.path.join(storage_path, 'site.html')

                with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:

                    file.write(response.text)

                toast("Webpage source saved")

            else:

                toast("Failed to save webpage source.")

        except Exception as e:

            toast('Please check your Internet Connection')

            print(str(e))

MainApp().run()
```

This is my `main.py`. I've mentioned everything about permission.  During run time my app asks for `media and photo` access permission but don't asks for file access permission.That's why my app can't save the file `site.html`.I've mentioned every possible permission in `buildozer.spec` file but still not working.But other apps like `PicsArt` ask for `photo,media and file` access permission. But my app don't. Please help me.My `Android version is 11`

[This is how my app look likes during run time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98hFF.jpg)

[And this how other apps look likes during run time.I want my app to ask the same permissions like this app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkcXA.jpg)

I need file access permission to create file

Comment: `my app can't save the file site.html` Full path please. Tell where you try to save that file.

Comment: ```/storage/emulated/0/Download/```

Comment: Could it be that the correct folder name is `Downloads`? Notice the `s`.

Comment: `During run time my app asks for media and photo access permission` ?? That can not be done on an Android 11 device. There you can only ask for READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: And that Files is for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. And we dont know what you have in manifest.

Comment: I noticed that my app works in Android 8. In ```Android 8``` it asks for ```photo,media and file access permission``` but in ```Android 11``` it only asks for ```photo and media access permission``` in my mainfest i've used legacy permission. So how do i fix the problem which is happening in ```Android 11```

Answer (score 1):

In an Android 11 device your app cannot write files in root of external storage.

Instead use one of the public directories in external storage like DCIM, Pictures, Documents, Download and so on.

Comment: I tried filename = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/site.html/' but not working getting permission denied error.

Comment: You should first care for the WRITE permission.

Comment: If you look at my given code carefully you can find that i have already mentioned read, write permission but not working. Also i have give the screenshots of my app.. If you look them you can figure out what I'm asking for